# Why does READC operation take the previously selected value in a single selection list made by single page subfile?

Tags: ibm-midrange

I am making a display file with a single selection list created by a single page subfile. With this implementation I found two problems.

The first one is that when I pressed Enter to select an option for the first time when the display file had been loaded, the READC operation in the RPGLE would return the correct value (it returns the character string in the subfile record). When I pressed Enter again with a different option selected, the value from the previous Enter press was returned. In subsequent turns it kept returning the value of the selection just before it. I added a second READC after the first one in the program just to see what would happen, and found out that both READC returned values. The first one returned the value from the previous selection, the second returned the value I had currently selected.

The second problem is that selecting the same option for multiple times did not work, i.e. it only worked for the first time and if I tried to select it again immediately it did not respond.

I had applied the same logic to another single selection list made of load all subfile and it did not have any of these problems. Does it mean that single page subfile is not suitable for making single selection list?

Here is the DDS for the subfile:

```
A                R ITFMAT02
A                  S1OPTN          50 A 6 11
A                R ITFMAT01
A                                           SFLCLT(ITFMAT02)
A 27                                        SFLDSP
A 28                                        SFLCLR
A 29                                        SFLEND
A                                           CF12(12)
A                                           SFLSNGCHC(*AUTOSLT)
```

Here is the RPGLE main loop:

```
C        *IN12     DOWEQ       *OFF
C                  EXFMT       ITFMAT01
C        *IN12     IFEQ        *ON
C                  LEAVE
C                  ENDIF
C                  READC       ITFMAT02
C                  MOVEL       S0OPTN         W1OPTN
                     .
                     .
                     .
C                  ENDDO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example.  I suspect you haven't been clearing the choice control field.

```
 A*
 A          R ITFMAT02                  SFL
 A            CTL            1Y 0H      SFLCHCCTL
 A            S1OPTN        50A     6 11
 A*
 A          R ITFMAT01
 A                                      SFLCTL(ITFMAT02)
 A  27                                  SFLDSP
 A N28                                  SFLDSPCTL
 A  28                                  SFLCLR
 A  29                                  SFLEND
 A                                      SFLSIZ(15)
 A                                      SFLPAG(05)
 A                                      CF12(12)
 A                                      SFLSNGCHC(*AUTOSLT)
 A            SFLRRN         4S 0H      SFLRCDNBR(CURSOR)
 A                                  1 30'Title'
 A            CHOICE         4S 0   3  1
 A                                  4  5'Choose one'
```

And the RPG.  I don't normally work in fixed format but tried to mirror the existing style.

```
 fsotest    cf   e             workstn
 f                                     SFILE(itfmat02:RRN)

 c* clear sfl
 c                   z-add     1             sflrrn
 c                   setoff                                       272829
 c                   seton                                        28
 c                   write     itfmat01
 c                   setoff                                       28
 c* load sfl
 c     1             do        9             rrn               4 0
 c                   movel     rrn           s1optn
 c                   write     itfmat02
 c                   seton                                        27
 c                   enddo

 C     *IN12         DOWEQ     *OFF
 C                   EXFMT     ITFMAT01

 C     *IN12         IFEQ      *ON
 C                   LEAVE
 C                   ENDIF

 C                   READC     ITFMAT02                               80
 C  n80              do
 C                   movel     rrn           choice
 C                   z-add     0             ctl
 C                   update    itfmat02
 C                   enddo
 C                   ENDDO

 c                   seton                                        lr
```

Comment: I never use this SFLCHCCTL keyword in my implementations and they usually worked just fine. I suspect that it has something to do with single page subfile implementation itself, not the single choice list part.

Comment: The posted DDS was not a complete subfile.  SFLSIZ and SFLPAG were missing, etc.  So it was difficult to know what is meant by 'single page subfile'.  In my opinion, if you have a choice subfile with SFLSIZ>SFLPAG and it works and then the one and only thing you change is to make SFLSIZ=SFLPAG and it fails, you should call IBM support and report a bug.

Comment: The point of being single page subfile is that every time when Page up and Page down key are pressed, the current subfile page will be reloaded entirely. Yes, SFLSIZ=SFLPAG is part of this implementation but I cannot really say that this is responsible for the problem.

Comment: Is it possible for single selection to coexist with other input fields in the same display?

Comment: Never mind about it now. I have found the real cause of the problem. The default system setting is that a subfile record will not be automatically deselected. So when I press Enter again READC will read the previously selected one because it is still in the status of being selected. The solution is to use SFLCHCCTL in DDS to reset the status back to available. My previous working implementation actually reloads the subfile again every time after a record has been selected so it has no problem. Well, thanks anyway.

Comment: The intent is that the user makes a choice and the program continues on - subfile is not re-displayed.  If you need to re-display the choice subfile, it's probably because the choice made was inappropriate and the user needs to choose another one.  Typically, this means disabling the inappropriate choice with SFLCHCCTL and letting the user try again.

Answer (score 0):

The READC behaviour is exactly as expected.  The 'Changed' part of Read Changed reads something called a Modified Data Tag.  If the user makes a change to a subfile record - any change at all including the space bar - the MDT is set on for that record.  This means if a user touches multiple records, multiple MDTs are set on.  Typical use is to put READC in a loop in order for the RPG program to process each touched record.  As for why the MDTs are not being turned off, are you using `SFLNXTCHG`?

Not sure about the second problem; post the DDS and RPG you're using.

Comment: It is defined to be a single selection list. Shouldn't it just return what I have selected and nothing else? Like I said, it worked fine for the load all subfile. I did not use SFLNXTCHG in the DDS.